# AngularJS unit test check if function without methods have been called

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm using Jasmine to unit test my Angular app. It's pretty easy to test if a method of a function has been called using something like:

```
spyOn($rootScope, "$emit");
expect($rootScope.$emit).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

But I can't find a way to check when a function has been called (without a method), for e.g. I'm using `$anchorScroll()`; in one controller and I have no idea where to apply the above code to this guy. I've seen some Jasmine examples where they were using `expect(window.myFunction()).toHaveBeenCalled()`, but this doesn't work with Angular's DI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't try it myself at the minute but maybe you could just inject a mock `$anchorScroll` instead?

```
var $anchorScroll = jasmine.createSpy('anchorScroll');

$controller('MyCtrl', {
    $anchorScroll: $anchorScroll
});

expect($anchorScroll).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

This should just create a blank spy, one which will take any arguments and do nothing but keep track of the calls for test usage.

Comment: I had the impression I tried that also ... but it seems I was doing something wrong. It works!